# Difference between hidden and deprecated object

Tags: business-objects

We have below three state of object in BI 4.x business layer.

1. Active (will use for reporting).
2. Hidden (will not available for reporting).
3. Deprecated (will not available for reporting).

Both hidden and deprecated objects will not available for reporting and both type of object we can convert into active object in future.
Can you please let me know difference between hidden and deprecated objects and in which scenario we will use the deprecated object in our universe.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 1):

- Active: Object is visible in the Query Panel. This is the default state.
- Hidden: Object is valid but not available in the Query Panel (used by other objects as a hidden object).
- Deprecated: Object is hidden and not valid. One possible use for this state is when the target database field no longer exists, but you want to keep the object for possible future use.

https://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir4/en/xi4sp6_info_design_tool_en.pdf